# CSS overflow: show entirely or hide

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to have HTML text which hides itself completely if it overflows? (rather than the clipping behavior of `overflow: hidden`)

Comment: Without JavaScript, you'll have to hack it using `@media` rules for viewport-widths, or using a `float:` element that pushes elements into the hidden area of the containing box if it gets too narrow. I suggest you experiment and post your results here.

Comment: Do you mean if the text overflows, then the all text does not get displayed at all? Sort of hide everything if everything cannot be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Put text into chunks like this:

```
<p style="display:inline-block;">This text is a chunk.</p>
<p style="display:inline-block;">This text is a chunk.</p>
<p style="display:inline-block;">This text is a chunk.</p>
```

This should either show the whole `inline-block` or hide it.

Comment: Not necessarily true. The text will wrap to a new line if it overflows. The OP wants the *entire* text to either be hidden or overflow: http://jsfiddle.net/1r5Lr0rg/ .. this isn't possible with pure CSS anyways..

Comment: @JoshCrozier Oh, I see. I think you'd need jQuery for that. (Should I delete this answer?)